# Attribute Error: list object has no attribute 'insert_many'

Tags: python, list, attributes, attributeerror

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient


clusler = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://dbuser:<****>@cluster0.w1jsy.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db =clusler ["test"]
collection =["test"]

post1={"_id":5,"name":"nour"}
post2 ={"_id":6,"name":"amir"}
x=collection.insert_many([post1,post2])
```

Upon running this code, I get this error:

> AttributeError: list object has no attribute 'insert_many'

Comment: Define `collection` like this:  `collection = db["test"]`. Also see https://gist.github.com/jpautom/abee7ed7e6241bb8f574.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
collection =["test"]
```

you define `collection` as a standard Python list. Later:

```
x=collection.insert_many([post1,post2])
```

you attempt to call `insert_many` on `collection`. Lists do not have this function, thus resulting in an `AttributeError`; you are attempting to call a function that does not exist.